# Clipping Edges in a bitboard

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, chess

I am using bitboards to generate attack tables for rooks, bishops, and queens. During my research of magic bitboards, it seems I need to clip the edges of all of my attack tables. I store my bitboards in a long, with square a1 being the LSB and square h8 being the MSB, moving row by row. Here is an example of an attack table for a rook on square c2:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

My problem is that I need to make all the ones on the edge of the bitboard 0s. At first I tried &ing each attack table with a binary long representing a border clip that looks like this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Now this works for most squares in the center, but for attack tables on the edges it clips it in error. SO for a rook on h8:

Initial attack table:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Expected Result:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Actual Result:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

How should i approach this so that it only clips the end of each attack ray? I realize my bit logic is off. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to make the outer cells zeros?

Comment: Please explain how you store the table. From what I read, I guessed you store the 64 bits in a `long`. However, the order of bits remains unclear. Do you use rows or columns? Where is the MSB and where is the LSB? Maybe you can add the `long` representation of each graphical example in you question by [edit]ing. That would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of masking out the bits at the border using a constant mask, use a dynamically generated mask.

Example, the rook (`♜`) is on field **F6**, so we generate a mask where **F**1, **F**8, A**6**, and H**6** are set. Then we use that mask to turn of those bits in your attack pattern.

```
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0   8
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   7
1 0 0 0 0 ♜ 0 1   6
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   5
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   4
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   3
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   2
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0   1

A B C D E F G H
```

In this solution I assume that you encode the 64 squares row-wise inside a `long`. The square A1 is the LSB and the square H8 is the MSB. Therefore above example would be represented by `2305984846213677088L = 0x2000810000000020L = 0b0000010000000000000100000010000000000000000000000000000000000100000L`

```
/** 
 * @param x 0-based index for the columns A to H (0=A_, 1=B_, ...)
 * @param y 0-based index for the rows 1 to 8 (0=_1, 1=_2, ...)
 */
long rookEndpoints(int x, int y) {
  long topBtm = 1L << x;
  return (0b10000001L << (8 * y)) | (topBtm << (8 * 7)) | topBtm; 
}

...
attackPattern &= ~rookEndpoints(x, y)
```